# List: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Code:

```
from itertools import permutations
L = list(input().split())
List=[]
for char in L[0]:
    List.append(char)
length = int(L[1])
###
List.sort()  
###
for ele in permutations(List,length):
    for i in ele:
        print(i,end="")
    print()
```

On writing this piece of code the program is running absolutely fine. But
on replacing the line between comment lines with:

```
List = List.sort()
```

This error is rising: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
I'm not able to understand this anomaly

Comment: `List.sort()` doesn't create a new list. It modifies the original list.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to assign the result of list.sort(), the list will be sorted just use:

```
List.sort()
```

from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> This method modifies the sequence in place for economy of space when
>   sorting a large sequence. To remind users that it operates by side
>   effect, it does not return the sorted sequence (use sorted() to
>   explicitly request a new sorted list instance).